# How to call an array's value with a variable within jade

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, pug

Can't figure out why exactly a variable can't be used to help call a value in an array with JS/Jade. This is being called inside a script on a `.jade` file.

The array contains roughly 400 entries and one of the entries is as follows:

```
myFood[10]['Cake'] = 50
```

When using the variable `i` instead of directly putting in the number `10` an error occurs.

Works:

```
alert (i)                     // 10
alert (#{myFood[10]['Cake']}) // 50
```

Error:

```
alert (#{myFood[i]['Cake']})  // Error, Cannot read property 'Cake' of undefined.
```

Comment: Where is your `i` variable coming from? Looks like it's a string

Comment: @AntoineBolvy `var i = 10;` Right above the alerts being called.

Comment: You are mixing jade and javascript code. The `var` line is interpreted on the client's browser, but `#{myFood[i]['Cake']}` is interpreted on the server where `i` is not defined.
You have to use a jade loop. Will post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, know that Jade recently was renamed to ["pugjs"](https://pugjs.org/).

I'm assuming that `i` is a javascript variable as you stated in the comments.

The pug (jade) context and the browser Javascript context are two very different things, so if you define `i` in browser Javascript, jade will not see it as a variable, just plaintext waiting to be interpreted by the browser. That's why `myFood[i]` is `undefined` and thus resulting in this error.

The correct way to define a jade variable is by prefixing your line by a dash (`-`), as described [here](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html).

The full code is:

```
- var i = 10;
alert (#{i})                  // 10
alert (#{myFood[10]['Cake']}) // 50
```

You note that I also changed the first alert to tell pug to replace the `#{i}` part by the actual value of `i`.

If you want to access each value I would highly suggest that you use [loops](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html) instead of using an `i` to access the array.

Mixing pug and javascript is a bit tricky, so good luck!